# use App.xaml.cs to create static instance of Class Library

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class library called `SGDataLibrary` with a class `SGMemberDataOp.cs` that holds all the data operations and gets the connection string to the database through the `app.config`.

Here is the connection string

```
 <add name="SimpleGym.Properties.Settings.SGYMConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=owner\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SGYM;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the `SGMemberDataOp.cs` class

```
namespace SGDataLibrary
{
   public class SGMemberDataOp
   {
      private string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.SGYMConnectionString;
```

Here is the code I am writing in my `App.xaml.cs` file

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
     ---->private static SGMemberDataOp sgMemberDataOp = new SGMemberDataOp();
     public static SGMemberDataOp SGMemberDataOp
     {
        get { return sgMemberDataOp; }
     }
 }
```

The line with the arrow is throwing an exception

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at some code where I do this but

```
private static SGMemberDataOp sgMemberDataOp;

 public static SGMemberDataOp SGMemberDataOp
 {
    get { return sgMemberDataOp; }
 }

public App()
{
    try
    {
        sgMemberDataOp = new SGMemberDataOp();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Startup failed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Newing it as a private did not work and not sure why.

Comment: Thanks for the help marked yours as right however it was me being a fool and adding the wrong dll to the reference...Hate it when I do something like this Thanks again for your help